# unexpected FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

while i am sending data from one activity to another activity i am getting below exception.
May be this is silly question.But i am new to Android

```
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    ... 11 more
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at kc.krishna.messagesending.Message.messgaeSend(Message.java:36)
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    ... 14 more
```

Message.java

```
ublic class Message extends Activity {

    TextView sending;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send);
        sending = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }




    public void messgaeSend(View v)
    {
        Intent sendIntent = null;
        String sendText = sending.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sendText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sendIntent.putExtra("SEND_MESSAGE", sendText);
        sendIntent = new Intent(Message.this,Receive.class);
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }

}
```

I am getting Exception at below line.

```
sendIntent.putExtra("SEND_MESSAGE", sendText);
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You've added `@SuppressWarnings("null")` to hide the compiler warning about exactly this issue. Suppressing the warnings is rarely the right way to get rid of them. As for the fix itself, see ρяσѕρєя K's answer.

Comment: Read the log - that's why it's there!  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 21:35:59.164: E/AndroidRuntime(17721):    at kc.krishna.messagesending.Message.messgaeSend(Message.java:36)`  messageSend(), line 36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendIntent` is `null` and you are trying to call method `putExtra`. Move `sendIntent.putExtra` after calling Intent constructor as:

```
sendIntent = new Intent(Message.this,Receive.class);
sendIntent.putExtra("SEND_MESSAGE", sendText);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```